# AutoCompleteTextField does not respect minimum length on load

Tags: codenameone

On load, when I focus or select the AutoCompleteTextField , the suggestions are showed right away eventhough I set the minimumLength  to 4.

This is what is going on:
1) On load , all suggestions are shown in this example
2) Only after I start typing the suggestions behave correctly and they wouldn't show until we meet the 4 character criteria.

You can recreate this issue with the code below from a barebone hello world.

```
    public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");

    ListModel<String> suggestionsModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    suggestionsModel.addItem("Apple");
    suggestionsModel.addItem("Banana");
    suggestionsModel.addItem("Chocolate");
    suggestionsModel.addItem("Elk");
    suggestionsModel.addItem("Fish");
    AutoCompleteTextField search = new AutoCompleteTextField(suggestionsModel);

    search.setMinimumLength(4);

    suggestionsModel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(int oldSelected, int newSelected) {
            System.out.println("SUGGESTION SELECTED"+suggestionsModel.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    });
    hi.add(search);

    hi.show();
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bug, can you please file an issue on the git project?

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug on Codename One side... I experienced the same thing. Here is a link for you to file an issue and it will be fixed 
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new

**EDIT:**

According to Shai's answer to your previous question, I doubt if the behavior will be changed due to other actions that rely on it.